# Error trying to send json to WebAPI controller method using curl

Tags: c#, json, curl, asp.net-web-api

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string vehicleDescriptors)
{
    var vehicles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<VehicleDescriptorModel>>(vehicleDescriptors);

    MvcApplication.HubHelper.DataChanged(vehicles);
}
```

My json file contents:

```
{
  vehicleDescriptors:
    [
        {
            "Id":"A20940",
            "Type":"AUGER",
            "Organization":"OPERATIONS",
            "Office":"South Boston",
            "ReportedTimestamp":"\\/Date(1406218241000)\\/",
            "ReceivedTimestamp":"\\/Date(1406218227000)\\/",
            "Latitude":36.71,
            "Longitude":-78.9061,
            "Speed":0,
            "Heading":345,
            "Proximity":86978.617892562324
        }
    ]
}
```

the curl statement I'm running:

```
curl "http://localhost/Web/api/vehicledescriptor/Post" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data @vehicleDescriptors.json
```

I've also tried:

```
curl "http://localhost/Web/api/vehicledescriptor/Post" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @vehicleDescriptors.json
```

I'm getting this error when it tries to deserialize, and when I debug, the vehicleDescriptors parameter is null:

```
{
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value",
"ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException",
"StackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Deserialization is done automatically by WebAPI, your method should be something like this `public void Post([FromBody] List<VehicleDescriptor> vehicleDescriptors)`

Comment: I think that's the right direction, but it's still coming in with no items.  I tried List, and also just an array of VehicleDescriptorModel, no dice, any more suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to change contentType to `application/json` in curl's parameters

Comment: actually I did that, and if I change the parameter to an object, I get something (a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject), so I think I just need to figure out why it's not seeing that as an array or list.

Comment: Seems like WebAPI deserialiazes it to an object which has a single property  `vehicleDescriptors` which is a List.

Comment: figured it out, didn't need that vehicleDescriptors on it :)

Comment: OK Now write an answer, so that everyone get benefit of it.

Comment: You should answer so you get the points, you pointed me in the correct direction, I'll update it with the little changes I did.

Comment: I have enough points, and you know better what you have done. I've never worked with WebAPI. Just wild guesses from your comments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on help from L.B and some trial and error I got there, there were a couple of issues:

1. As L.B said, the deserialization is automagic so your parameter will come through as the deserialized object
2. The json was slightly off.  If you can it is better to serialize your object in code and grab that rather than try to build your own :)
3. The curl command was good, you need to use application/json content-type header.

Here are the working versions:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] List<VehicleDescriptorModel> vehicleDescriptors)
{
    MvcApplication.HubHelper.DataChanged(vehicleDescriptors);
}
```

json:

```
[
   {
      "Id":"A20940",
      "Type":"AUGER",
      "Organization":"OPERATIONS",
      "Office":"South Boston",
      "ReportedTimestamp":"\\/Date(1406218241000)\\/",
      "ReceivedTimestamp":"\\/Date(1406218227000)\\/",
      "Latitude":36.71,
      "Longitude":-78.9061,
      "Speed":0,
      "Heading":345,
      "Proximity":86978.617892562324
   }
]
```

curl:

```
curl "http://localhost/Web/api/vehicledescriptor/Post" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @vehicleDescriptors.json
```

Comment: I guess, your json in question can be used when you have a method which takes more than one parameter.